# How can I inject an Action to controller from custom action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a custom action filter (say `CustomActionFilter`) where I override `OnActionExecuting` to validate the Action's input parameter such that if the input param is `null` then the filter will render a view (say view `MyErrorView`) contains "Index not found" text else it will let execute the regular Action method.

My Action Method:

```
    [CustomActionFilter]
    public ActionResult Index(int indexId)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

My Filter's overridden method:

```
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Trace.Write("(Custom Action Filter)Action Executing: " + filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName);

        if (filterContext.ActionParameters["indexId"] == null)
        {
            //my code goes here
        }
    }
```

What code I need to put in the of condition to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Trace.Write("(Custom Action Filter)Action Executing: " + filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName);

        if (filterContext.ActionParameters["indexId"] == null)
        {
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "MyErrorView",
            ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData,
            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
        }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    }
```

Comment: `View("MyErrorView")`, where `View` method is member of Controller abstract class. Does it suggest to inherit my custom filter class from `Controller` class?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. Do you have any errors when you implement my answer?

Comment: (ActionExecutingContext) inherits from the ControllerContext class so you can use (filterContext.Result)

Comment: Yes, but you are calling the View() method?